# show Port Data Types

Tags: matlab, simulink

In the newest Simulink version it is possible to show the Port Data Types.

I found via Google a description how to setup that in R2013.
(http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/simulink/ug/displaying-signal-properties.html)

I know there is a possibility to do that in R2009 as well. I saw it. 
But can'T find the option in the menues.

Do someone know how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `Format` menu, there should be an option `Port Data Types` somewhere in there.